# Moment not formatting UK date correctly

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to format a date to UK format but despite using what I believe to be the correct format. The dates with a single digit day (1...9) are transposing the days and month although all other days are formatting correctly.  Something basic I'm sure.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Single date with icon
        $(function(){
            $("#date-icon").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: new Date(), 
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>'
            });
        });
        // Popup time interval
        $(function() {
            $( "#depart_date" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: new Date(), 
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>',
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#return_date" ).datepicker( "option", "from_date", selectedDate );
                }
            });
            $( "#return_date" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>',
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#depart_date" ).datepicker( "option", "to_date", selectedDate );
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

And then to format it:

```js
var FromDateValue = $('#depart_date').val();
var ToDateValue = $('#return_date').val();
var FromDateValue = Date.parse(FromDateValue)
var ToDateValue = Date.parse(ToDateValue)    

moment.locale('en-gb');                  
var a = moment(ToDateValue, "dd-mm-yyyy");
var b = moment(FromDateValue, "dd-mm-yyyy");
var days = a.diff(b, 'days') +1  // =1
alert(ToDateValue)
```

This is where I receive the incorrect formatted date.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the way you are parsing `ToDateValue` and `FromDateValue` using moment.

Please note that tokens are case sensitive and `dd` stands for day of the week, `mm` stands for minutes (`0..59`) and there is no lowercase `yyyy`. You have to use uppercase `DD` for day of month (`1..31`), uppercase `MM` for month number (`1..12`) and uppercase `YYYY` for 4 digit year.

See [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs. Your code could be like the following:

```js
moment.locale('en-gb');                  
var a = moment(ToDateValue, "DD-MM-YYYY");
var b = moment(FromDateValue, "DD-MM-YYYY");
var days = a.diff(b, 'days') +1  // =1
alert(ToDateValue)
```